# Finding the original ODE using a solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Does there exist a linear-homogeneous ODE with constant coefficients so that
$$y(x) = x \cos^2(x)-\sin(x)$$
is its solution?

If it does exist, how can I know what the original ODE is
or how can I say there's no such ODE?

I've tried changing $y(x)$ to
$$y(x) =x \, (\cos(2x)+1)-\sin(x) \\
y(x) = x \, \cos(2x)+x-\sin(x).$$

Now I've figured few things:

1. that if $y(x) =x \, \cos(2x)+x-\sin(x)$ is a solution
   then $y(x) = x + \cos(2x) - \sin(x)$ is also a solution
2. because the solution consist of $\cos$ and $\sin$ then the roots of the ODE must consist of a root with the form $k=a+bi$ and $k=a-bi$.

Other than that I'm pretty stuck with how I should move forward from here.

Edit:
Correct answer after confirming with WolfarmAlpha
[image: screen capture from WolfarmAlpha]

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: ODR? Are we talking about an outdoor rink? But seriously, please show us your try even if it's at a dead end. I suspect the answer is no.

Comment: Edited, thank you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Notice that:

$$y(x) = x \cos^2(x)-\sin(x) = \frac{x\cos(2x)}{2} + \frac{x}{2} - \sin(x).$$

**I assume that the starting ODE is linear, time-invariant and homogeneous.**

Let $D(\lambda)$ be the characteristic polynomial of the ODE such that $y(x)$ is one solution. According to the form of $y(x)$, we can observe that:

1. $D(\lambda)$ has $(\lambda^2 + 4)^2$ as factor in order to have $x\cos(2x)$ in the solution;
2. $D(\lambda)$ has $\lambda^2$ as factor in order to have $x$ in the solution;
3. $D(\lambda)$ has $(\lambda^2 + 1)$ as factor in order to have $\sin(x$) in the solution.

Accordingly, the characteristic polynomial can (I guess it is minimal) be:

$$D(\lambda) = \lambda^2(\lambda^2 + 4)^2(\lambda^2 + 1) = \lambda^8 + 9 \lambda^6 + 24 \lambda^4 + 16 \lambda^2,$$

corresponding to the linear, time-invariant and homogeneous ODE

$$y^{(8)}(x) + 9y^{(6)}(x) + 24y^{(4)}(x) + 16y^{(2)}(x) = 0,$$

where $y^{(n)}(x)$ is the $n$-th derivative of $y(x)$.

The general solution of such ODE is:

$$y(x) = A+Bx + C\cos(2x) + D\sin(2x) + Ex\cos(2x) + Fx\sin(2x) + G\cos(x) +H\sin(x),$$

and the solution proposed by the OP corresponds to the case where:

$$\begin{cases}
A = 0\\
B = \frac{1}{2}\\
C = 0\\
D = 0\\
E = \frac{1}{2}\\
F = 0\\
G = 0\\
H = -1
\end{cases}$$

In a Cauchy problem context, the parameters $A, B, \ldots, H$ are determined by the provided initial condition.

Comment: Your answer is exactly what I needed! Thank you very much

Comment: Shouldn't it be $(\lambda^2+4)^2$

Comment: @enzotib you are correct, it should be  $(\lambda^2+4)^2$

Comment: Yeah, you are right, thanks!